finding text files from USB disk
I had a few Openoffice text files in a big folder, along with other stuff, I put that folder in a USB disk, I can find everything back except the text files, how could I get them back ? I'm on Xubuntu, and after I've put the folder on the disk, I sent the copy left in the trash bin and deleted it.

If you deleted them then they are gone.

Which version of XUbuntu are you using?

As its text, I'd likely use fgrep to search for it, OR if you know when created (and preserved file-system metadata in copy to USB media) I'd search for something created/edited at the appropriate date (few weeks or so either way).  Either way you've provided few specifics; no file-system details, no release of Xubuntu, no clue as to how copied etc

This question is similar to: How to recover deleted files?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

First make image of disk. sudo dd if=/dev/sdc of=./usb.img bs=4M status=progress 
Then install and use ''testdisk''.
sudo apt install testdisk
Then run testdisk on image file of usbtestdisk ./usb.img

Then press enter key on proceed.



Then press continue.





